# How to change the value of table data to 'available' in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `production.productioninventory` with these columns and sample data:

```
productID   shelf
-------------------
  1           A
  2           B 
  3           C
  4          N/A
```

I want to change shelf data into 'available' which are not N/A

For example:

```
productID   shelf
-------------------
1           available
2           available
3           available
4           not available
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This will work:**

1) Using `CASE`

```
UPDATE production.productioninventory 
SET shelf = CASE  
                WHEN shelf = 'N/A' THEN 'not available' 
                ELSE 'available' 
            END
```

2) Using `IIF`

```
UPDATE production.productioninventory 
SET shelf = IIF(shelf = 'N/A', 'not available' , 'available')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select productID, 
       case when shelf = 'N/A' 
            then 'not available'
            else 'available'
       end as shelf
from productioninventory
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE production.productioninventory SET shelf = 'not available' WHERE shelf = 'N/A'
UPDATE production.productioninventory SET shelf = 'available' WHERE shelf <> 'N/A'
```

Comment: @Squirrel just for simplicity, you can use case when structure and merge it to one statement

Answer (score 0):

You may not even need to change the data.  Instead, just add a computed column:

```
alter table production.productioninventory
    add availability as (case when shelf = 'N/A' then 'not available' else 'available' end);
```

This becomes part of the table definition and is available in your queries.